# show text file on hyperlink event in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I have these number of `<a href />`links in a HTML page:

```
<a ...>
<a ...>
.....
<a ...>
```

What I want is on the click of each link I have to show a text file on same html page. 
a text file can be shown in a `textarea` or `iframe`.

How can I accomplish that?

.........**EDIT**.............. 
correct code

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Ajax Test</title>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function(){
                $("a").click(function(e){
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $.get( $(this).attr("href") ).done(function(e){
                        $("textarea").html(e);
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="{{STATIC_URL }}foo.txt">foo bar</a><br>
        <textarea></textarea>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This seems pretty straight forward to me. What have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [AJAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) to get the text file data from the server, then put it into the text field.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/63BLB/

```
$("a").click(function(e){              //select all <a>
    e.preventDefault();                //remove default link effect
    $.get( $(this).attr("href") )      /*AJAX (using jQuery)..
                                         ..and insert the URL of text file*/
    .done(function(e){                 //When it is downloaded,
        $("textarea").html(e);         //shows it in <textarea>
    });
});
```

If you are new to jQuery, you may want to check out [their documentation](http://api.jquery.com/), especially [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). :)

Note: You can only fetch text files in the [same origin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy).
Note 2: The code above is written using jQuery. If you do not want to use jQuery, you will have to do [the whole native](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) [`new XMLHttpRequest` thing](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/xhr/raw-file/tip/Overview.html).

Comment: i have edited my post. text of file is not loaded in textarea when clicked.

Comment: @naveenyadav - Are you using jQuery? Did you include it?

Comment: yes i did included that

Comment: @naveenyadav - I see. The problem is that you have copied the code I have in jsFiddle. I actually modified it so that it works in jsFiddle. Instead, you should use the code I posted here. Let me know if it still doesn't work.

Comment: can you post complete code in your answer. i tried above code but didn't worked

Comment: @naveenyadav - It *is* the complete code...

Comment: @naveenyadav - Complete test site: http://silent-text-346.appspot.com/ajax.html

Comment: i have used the exact code of above url but still no success. I could not figure out why it is not working.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41140/discussion-between-derek--and-naveen-yadav)